# drawing on an NSImage

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm trying to draw a circle onto an NSImage and then display it on the screen. I want to do this repeatedly so that with each new circle the old ones are not shown. If I use the code below the circle is drawn but each time I draw a new one the old ones are still present.

```
-(void)drawPointToImage:(float)x y:(float)y
{
    // drawpoint and update
    float diameter1 = 20, x_plot, y_plot; // keep diameter1

    if ( isnan(x) || isnan(y) || x < 0.0001 || y < 0.0001 ) {
        return;
    }

    x_plot = [self xToScreen:x];
    y_plot = [self yToScreen:y];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)]; // start with clean image
    image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"538x598.png"];//orginalImage;

    NSRect myRect1 = NSMakeRect(x_plot, y_plot, diameter1, diameter1);
    NSBezierPath *path1;
    path1 = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:myRect1];
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [path1 fill];

    imageView.image = image; // display to screen
}
```

So I tried the following but now the circles are not drawn at all. How can I draw a circle on a fresh image each time?

```
-(void)drawPointToImage:(float)x y:(float)y
{
    // drawpoint and update
    float diameter1 = 20, x_plot, y_plot; // keep diameter1

    if ( isnan(x) || isnan(y) || x < 0.0001 || y < 0.0001 ) {
        return;
    }

    x_plot = [self xToScreen:x];
    y_plot = [self yToScreen:y];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight)]; // start with clean image
    image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"538x598.png"];//orginalImage;

    [image lockFocus];

    NSRect myRect1 = NSMakeRect(x_plot, y_plot, diameter1, diameter1);
    NSBezierPath *path1;
    path1 = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:myRect1];
    [[NSColor blackColor] set];
    [path1 fill];

    [image unlockFocus];

    imageView.image = image; // display to screen
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you're using images at all, but when you assign to `image` using `imageName:`, you throw away (and leak) the one you alloc'd in the previous line.

Comment: I have a picture of a diagram that I want to plot a point onto, this point changes so I start with the clean image each time then draw the new point, I don't want the previous points to remain. I'm using ARC so I thought that takes care of the leak.

Comment: Maybe ARC takes care of the leak, but it's still pointless to throw an object away right after you create it.

Comment: My goal is to draw the point on the image, assign this new image to the imageView then delete it. Isn't this what I'm doing? Any ideas as to why I can't draw on the image?

Answer (score 0):

This works. For some reason the "drawAtPoint" command does not work, no image is drawn. Also, the image jumps about 20 pixels down and to the right the second time this is called.

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
//    return;
    // drawpoint and update
    float diameter1 = 10, x_plot, y_plot;

    if ( isnan(Cx) || isnan(Cy) || Cx < 0.0001 || Cy < 0.0001 ) {
        return;
    }

    x_plot = [self xToScreen:x]; // x is class-wide
    y_plot = [self yToScreen:y]; // y is class-wide


    NSImage *image;// = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(cieCanvasWidth, cieCanvasHeight)]; // start with clean image
    image = orginalImage; // start with clean image; orginalImage is class-wide

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

    [image drawInRect:cieRect fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];
//    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(500,500) fromRect:cieRect operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

    // draw point
    NSRect myRect1 = NSMakeRect(x_plot, y_plot, diameter1, diameter1);
    NSBezierPath *path1;
    path1 = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:myRect1];
    [[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
    [path1 fill];

    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

}
```